# Bootstrap tooltips in Ruby on Rails App Not Working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Running
`ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]`
and `Rails 4.2.5`

I'm trying to added bootstrap tooklips into a ruby tag `<%= link_to '', account, class: "fa fa-eye" %>` but it doesn't seem to work.

The syntax I used was

```
<%= link_to '', account, class: "fa fa-eye" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top %>
```

I placed the sample code from the bootstrap site

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</button>
```

just to make sure that the js was working correctly and it seem to be fine. I want to avoid installing bootstrap-tooltip-rails Gem or any other gem for that matter. Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Try: <%= link_to '', account, class: 'fa fa-eye', 'data-toggle': 'tooltip', 'data-placement':'top', title: 'Tooltip on top' %>

Comment: @william-holt Thanks. I see what I did wrong. It's always the simple things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution to adding bootstrap tooltips in Rails App**

```
<td><%= link_to ' Edit', edit_account_path(account), class: "fa fa-pencil-square-o", 'data-toggle': 'tooltip', 'data-placement':'top', title: 'Edit Client Account'  %></td>
```